# What is the total number of bases (base 2, base 10, etc)available in our number system?

Tags: number-systems

As we have different numeral bases in number system such as base 2(binary), base 10(decimal) etc. As binary (base 2) is smallest among all, is there a base value that is maximum?I was trying to search the total number of bases available in our number system?

I was checking for the same on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numeral_systems), but could not find a total count. I am not sure if there exists such total count on bases but just wanted to clarify with the community?

Comment: Each integer $b>1$ is a base. Some of them just have names (e.g., decimal, binary, hexadecimal, etc.; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix)

Comment: Any real number except -1, 0 and 1 can serve as a base.

Comment: I thought so..that there exists infinitely many bases and that led me to this search.. I was trying to see if a number is palindrome in any base(starting with 2) but then I got stuck at a point, where I had to provide the max value for base(something like stopping condition). I was not able to decide that what should be the max value for a base against which I can check a given number is palindrome and if it's not then I can conclude that the given input is not palindrome in any base.

Comment: Then you should ask your real question.  Once the base gets larger than the number, the number is represented by a single digit, which is guaranteed to be a palindrome. Your stopping condition becomes when the base is greater than the number.  The answer to your question is no, there is no number which is a palindrome in any base.  if you express $n$ in base $n$, it is $10$, which is not a palindrome.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I will update my post with this question as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a base in each positive natural number. There are countably infinitely many such numbers, so there are countably infinitely available bases.

(Think about it this way: for every positive integer, there exists a unique base in which that integer is $10$).

Comment: You mean 10, not 1.

Comment: I think you meant 10 not 1.  1 is 1 in all bases and 10 is n in all base n.

Comment: What about imaginary integers?

Comment: Good catch, I did mean 10, not 1. @ZelosMalum: I don't know what you mean with imaginary integers. Do you mean complex numbers? We don't have bases in them.

Comment: I meant $ni$, they can be used for a radic

Answer (score 0):

Any natural number greater than zero can be a base, so there are infinitely many.  Once you choose a base $b$, you can express any natural number $n$ as $a_0+b\cdot a_1+b^2\cdot a_2 + \ldots$ where all the $a$'s are in the range $0$ to $b-1$.  Base $10$ is what we are used to, base $2$ is common in computer usage, but the others work fine.  There is just no motivation to use them.  You can also have negative bases.  You can express $-37_{10}=1\cdot (-10)^2+7\cdot (-10)^1+7\cdot (-10)^0=177_{-10}$.  Arithmetic is no harder in these, but the numbers are longer, as this example shows.  It has two digits in base $10$, but three in base $-10$.  Some people have thought about fractional bases, some about real number bases.  Only the reals change the number of bases, driving it up to $\mathfrak c$, the power of the continuum.  If you work in base $\pi$ and allow digits up to $4$ you can represent all numbers (some with more than one representation) but $5_{10}$ becomes an unending decimal.  Aw c'mon.

Comment: Any real number except -1, 0 and 1 can serve as a base.

Comment: @BernardMasse  $1$ can serve.  To represent $n$ you have a string of $n \ 0$'s  This is the classic way naturals are represented in Turing machines.